# Sending message over SuperSocket

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm using SuperWebSocket library for work with websockets. My app is sending messages for connected clients. How to send data to another server that working on websockets too ?

```
using SuperSocket.SocketBase;
using System;
using SuperSocket.SocketBase.Protocol;

namespace SuperSocket_Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var appServer = new AppServer();
            appServer.Setup(123); //binding to 123 port
            appServer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("The server started successfully, press key 'q' to stop it!");

            appServer.NewRequestReceived += new RequestHandler<AppSession, StringRequestInfo>(appServer_NewRequestReceived);


            while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != 'q')
            {
                Console.WriteLine();                
            }
            appServer.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("The server was stopped!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        } 

        static void appServer_NewRequestReceived(AppSession session, StringRequestInfo requestInfo)
        {           
            session.Send(requestInfo.Body);            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SuperSocket -- it's only server-side lib. For Client-side you should use Websocket4net